# Block time and block size in Eris

Tags: proof-of-stake, eris-industries

I've seen in a video that the target block time for Casper will start with 4 seconds. Eris (now Monax) is using Tendermint which is also a PoS algorithm.

What is the block time in an Eris blockchain? Also, what's the block size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eris-DB essentially is running the EVM combined with Tendermint consensus. This translates to many of the properties that Tendermint has. It can reach finality at ~2 seconds and the block size is variable depending on what you want to put on your chain (Tendermint has some uniqueness in its finality). More can be found here:

https://github.com/tendermint/tendermint/wiki/Introduction

Source: I work at Monax.